# How to convert JSON array to java object

Tags: java, json, api, jackson

This is the json i'm sending via POST request

```
{
  "PIds" : [ "MOB123", "ELEC456"]
}
```

This is my class that receives the JSON,

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("/GetProductsInfo")
public List<ProductDetails> getProductsInfo(ProductIds productIds) {

    System.out.println(productIds + "   ");

    DBCursor<ProductDetails> dbCursor = collection.find(DBQuery.in("pid", productIds.getPIds()));

    List<ProductDetails> products = new ArrayList<>();
    while (dbCursor.hasNext()) {
        ProductDetails product = dbCursor.next();
        products.add(product);
    }
    return products;
}
```

Im converting the JSON array into the 'ProductIds' object, this is my POJO class

```
public class ProductIds
{
    @JsonProperty("PIds")
    private List<String> pIds;

    public List<String> getPIds()
    {
        return pIds;
    }

    public void setPIds(List<String> Pids)
    {
        this.pIds = Pids;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "ClassPojo [PIds = "+ pIds +"]";
    }
}
```

The problem for me here is that the JSON is not getting populated into the java object 'productIds' is NULL, I dont know why. Im new to Jackson can someone help me out. Thank you

Comment: Which REST library do you use? If Jersey what is your Jersey config? Have you registered Jackson feature? BTW, you may use List directly as argument for getProductsInfo.

Comment: You could take advantage of the `GET` verb and remove the word from your path: `GET /ProductsInfo`. Then `POST` could be reused on the same URI to create/update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to get the ID's out using .getJSONArray()?
Uses the org.json library.

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(jsoninput);

JSONArray jsonArray = obj.getJSONArray("PIds");
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using JAXB? Jersey? fasterxml.jackson? I'm getting the impression you are using several at the same time

RestClass:

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("/GetProductsInfo")
public List<ProductDetails> getProductsInfo(@RequestBody ProductIds productIds) {
   // etc
}
```

For JAXB:

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class ProductIds {
    @XmlElement("PIds")
    private List<String> pIds;

    public List<String> getPIds() {
        return pIds;
    }

    public void setPIds(List<String> Pids) {
        this.pIds = Pids;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ClassPojo [PIds = " + pIds + "]";
    }
}
```

Otherwise take a look at:

[Convert a JSON string to object in Java ME?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1395551/928952)

[How to convert the following json string to java object?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10308452/928952)

Comment: I'm using Jersey @Danielson

Comment: I'm uncertain but I think the above also works for Jersey

Comment: The @JsonProperty is for Jackson

Comment: The GET,POST annotation are for Jersey and in POJO the @JsonProperty is Jackson. Im using both jersey and jackson for my application

Comment: @RequestBody ProductIds productIds

Comment: There is no annotation as @RequestBody

Comment: Still get nothing if you change your argument type to String?

Comment: I get the JSON as String argument. It is not getting converted to java object, that is my problem

Comment: check this answer... http://stackoverflow.com/a/31022354/928952 It help to translate JSON string to Java Class