# Java - Jackson deserialization - how to deserialize an array of interface?

Tags: java, arrays, json, jackson, deserialization

I have arrays like these.

```
{
    ImplArray1:[
        {
            ...
        }
        , ...
    ],
    ImplArray2:[
        {
            ...
        }
        , ...
    ]
}
```

<strike>which both Impl1 and Impl2 implement same interface.</strike>

How can I deserialize both arrays into two List< Interface>?

Edited : My god. The question doesn't make sense at all. Really sorry for being bad at life.

What I mean is, an array ImplArray1 contains Impl1, and array ImplArray2 contains Impl2. Both Impl1 and Impl2 implement same interface. How can I deserialize both into List< Interface1>?

Comment: you mean Impl1 and Impl2 both implement same Interface?

Comment: maybe this answer helps, serializing/deserializing http://stackoverflow.com/a/31022354/928952

Answer (score 2):

The only way I managed to pull something that is close to the requirement, is if you have a super class that is extended by both implementations. The super class may implement the common interface

```
ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
TypeFactory tf = om.getTypeFactory();

// map key type
JavaType stringType = tf.constructType(String.class);
// map value type
JavaType listOfSuper = tf.constructParametrizedType(List.class, List.class, Super.class);
// map type
JavaType mapType = tf.constructMapType(Map.class, stringType, listOfSuper);
// finally, do the parsing
Reader fr = new FileReader("C://Temp/xx.json");
Map<String, List<Interface>> map = (Map<String, List<Interface>>)om.readValue(fr, mapType);

static interface Interface  
{
}

static class Super implements Interface 
{
    public String name = "";
    public int age = 0;
}

static class Impl1 extends Super 
{
}

static class Impl2 extends Super
{
}
```